# Borel measure which is not regular

Tags: measure-theory

I need an **example where a Borel measure is not regular**. I already proved that any finite Borel measure is regular and tight. The examples of irregular measures given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_measure#Examples) are too rigid and not so elegant, moreover I am not familiar with the concept of measurable cardinals.

So I want better examples.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Consider counting measure $\nu$ on Borel subsets of real line $\mathbb{R}$. Obviously, it is not regular, since $\nu(\{0\}) = 1$, while for every nonempty open set $U$ we have $\nu(U) = +\infty$.
The problem with counting measure here is that it is not locally finite.

Also note that not every finite Borel measure on metric space is tight. However, it is sufficient to ask for separability and completeness of metric space to  guarantee tightness of every finite Borel measure (Ulam's theorem).